# Why is \r not giving the same results on mac vscode as windows vscode

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

The following code should print the number of seconds passing from 0-10 and works as intended on windows vscode, however on mac's vscode the output takes 10 seconds as it should but only outputs

> 10 second has passed

However, if I change the \r to \n , the code works but i don't want to print a new line every time.

> 0 second has passed
>
> 1 second has passsed
>
> etc...

I've been searching for some time about this and i don't know what seems to be the issue...

The Code :

```
for(int i = 0;i<=10;i++)
{
    printf("\r %d second has passed",i);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from buffering. By disabling buffering on stdout, the text will be output immediately on calling `printf`. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int main() {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    for(int i = 0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        printf("\r %d second has passed",i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More efficient would be to _not_ do `setbuf`. Then, do `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`